# How to protect LEDs from high voltage during NPN transitor transitions?

Tags: transistors, led, npn, transient, led-matrix

I am using a 555 timer and an NPN transistor to drive an array of 12 LEDs from a 9v battery, and a potentiometer to control the duty cycle. I am concerned about the voltages the LEDs will be subjected to during the transistor's on/off transitions.

---

My simulated circuits:

#### Top Level

[image: Top Level Circuit Design]

#### PWM Driver

[image: 555 Timer Circuit Driver]

#### LED Array

[image: LED Array]

---

#### Simulated Output

[image: VLED Plot]

---

I understand that when the transistor is off, having 9v on the anode side of the LEDs is fine because there's no path to ground. Likewise, when the transistor is fully on, an operating voltage of just over 3 volts for my LEDs is fine. But real transistors won't transition between on and off instantaneously, so how can I protect my LEDs from voltage spikes that will either destroy them or wear them out faster? Is it even necessary for this circuit?

Comment: It does not directly answer your question, but please see [this SE Answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/22293/148777) regarding the placement of current-limiting resistors on parallel LEDs

Comment: @KevinKruse Bummer. Thanks for the link. I wasn't aware of that consideration. These LEDs are going into a guitar fretboard, so I guess I'm going to have to figure out where the hell to fit resistors in.

Comment: @KevinKruse This is an app note from OSRAM on the placement of resistors. https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-2496697/Comparison%20of%20LED%20circuits.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with the circuit.

The voltage across the LEDs take a bit of time to build up to the 3V because of capacitance the LEDs have. That's all you are seeing.

When the transistor turns on, the VLED voltage drops to about 0V quickly, then over a period of time the capacitance charges and the VLED voltage rises to a voltage such that the LEDs are conducting essentially all the current through R1.

Try plotting the **actual voltage** across the LEDs. If you are using LTspice, then just edit "V(vled)" to "V(vled) - V(vgnd) by right-clicking on the label and changing it in the Expression Editor. Also plot the **LED current**. You won't see excessive forward or negative voltage, nor will you see excessive LED current.

Comment: Plotting Vled vs Vgnd was a great suggestion. You're correct that it shows the actual LED voltage never rising above ~3v. Current stays in a reasonable range as well. Thanks for the explanation.